# UBound Value of Filter Output in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a 1D array for a value, and I've been trying to do this using the filter function, but when I write a small sub to test this, it doesn't work and I get a "type mismatch" error.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code?

```
Dim range1() As Variant
range1 = Sheet4.range("B3:B7")

Dim string1 As String
string1 = "hello"

If UBound(Filter(range1, string1)) >= 0 Then
    Sheet4.range("A1").Value = "Hello exists."
Else
    Sheet4.range("A1").Value = "Hello does not exist."
End If
```

Hello appears once in the selected range, so the result of the Ubound function should be 0, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use transpose to create a 1D array out of a range. [See this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

```
range1 = Application.Transpose(Sheet4.Range("B3:B7"))
```

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s(v=vs.90).aspx) *Filter Function* requires one-dimensional array of strings.

> Required. ***One-dimensional*** array of strings to be searched